# Translate text vertically / Transform text vertically

Tags: javascript, css

Here in this code on hover text moves horizontally. I want to move it vertically but I don't know which coordinates to change. If anyone could please help me out with the same.

I want to have the line animation along with the text transform animation like the cuberto website has in the header on hover.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/niyamvora/pen/YzerrMb)

```html
<body class="demo-1">
        <main>
            <ol class="content">
                <li class="content__item">
                    <a href="#" class="link link--leda" data-text="Transform Vertically">
                        <span>Transform Vertically</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
      </ol>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The horizontal animation relies on `translate3d`. That function takes three properties `x, y, z`.

In your existing code, the transformations on hover all change the `x` value. To move it vertically, you want to modify the `y` value.

Here is a quick example based on your code: https://codepen.io/29b6/pen/gOvowbw